# Writing Certain Integers from one array to another

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I've been trying to move the positive integers only from one array to another from an array with values
51 144 5 16 8 0 -2 14
6 -4 173
263 11 9345 -135
777

The code I have is

```
void pullfilename (string, string&);
void pullnegativenumbers (ofstream&, int, int[], int[]);
void pullpositivenumbers (ofstream&, int, int[], int[]);

int main()
{


ifstream input;
  ofstream output;
  string fname;

  pullfilename("input", fname);
  input.open(fname.c_str());
  pullfilename("output", fname);
  output.open(fname.c_str());

  int n=0;
  int list[50];
  int positive[50];

  input>>list[n];

while (input)
    {
      n++;
        input>>list[n];
    }

 pullnegativenumbers(output, n, list, positive);
 pullpositivenumbers(output, n, list, positive);

  return 0;
}

void pullfilename(string filetype,string& fname)
{
cout<<"Enter name of"<<filetype<<"file"<<endl;
  cin>>fname;
}
void pullnegativenumbers(ofstream& out, int n, int list[], int positive[])
{
int ncount=0;
 int pcount=0;
int nsum=0;
int naverage=0;
 int i;
 for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
     if (list[i]<0)
  {
    ncount++;
    nsum=nsum+list[i];
  naverage=nsum/ncount;
  out<<left<<setw(15)<<"Negative Values"<<endl;
  out<<left<<setw(6)<<"Count:"<<right<<setw(10)<<ncount<<endl;
  out<<left<<setw(4)<<"Sum:"<<right<<setw(10)<<nsum<<endl;
  out<<left<<setw(8)<<"Average"<<right<<setw(10)<<naverage<<endl;
  }
}
}

void pullpositivenumbers(ofstream& out, int n, int list[], int positive[])
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
if (n>=0)
      {
        list[i]=positive[i];
      }
  `out<<positive[i]<<endl;
}
```

It pulls my negative numbers to the side the way I'd like, but the output in the file for the positive array comes out to be -123908309???

Comment: Honestly, this is a 4 or 5 line program if you used `std::partition`.

Comment: This isn't a very robust program. It will break if the user enters more than 50 integers. There's nothing to check that. You are using string, so why not vector as well?

Comment: Your `pullNegativeNumbers` function doesn't make a lot of sense.  First, you pass a `positive` to it, and then do noting with this parameter.  Second, you are taking the average while you're looping.  Aren't you supposed to sum all the numbers first, and then when finished, divide by the number of numbers?  Also, your `pullNegativeNumbers` function looks nothing like your `pullPositiveNumbers` function.

Comment: I only need the positive numbers to be in an array, while the negatives just need to be counted, summed, averaged. So for the negatives, I see that it loops a few times and have managed to fix it, but I still don't know how to copy the rest of the positives to an separate array so I use them later. I've read the same code on several sites that says all I have to do it use   for (int i=0; i<50; i++);copy[i] = data[i];  but it doesn't seem to work, it just gives me one huge output

Comment: How are the integers stored in your file; are they on the same line separated by a space character or is each integer on its own line? Are you reading in a text file or reading it in binary?

Answer (score 2):

> but I still don't know how to copy the rest of the positives to an
>   separate array so I use them later.

You have a sequence of values, and you want to place the ones that satisfy a certain condition into an array.  That takes a simple loop, and even that isn't necessary if you use particular algorithm functions.

First, the thing that is wrong with your code is that you use `list` array to not only get the original values, but to also do this:

```
void pullpositivenumbers(ofstream& out, int n, int list[], int positive[])
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
   if (n>=0)
   {
      list[i]=positive[i];  // you are storing an uninitialized value in list[i]
   }
  out<<positive[i]<<endl;
}
```

This is totally wrong in that you are overwriting your original array you read in with some value from the `positive` array.

The second thing that's wrong is that `positive` and `list` must use different indices.  You are reading from `list` using index `i`, but you need a separate index variable for `positive`.  What if you had this:

```
list -> -1, -2, -3, -4, 10
```

When you get to `list[4]` you get to the `10`.  However, you are supposed to store the 10 at `positive[0]` not `positive[4]`, since the numbers before 10 were all negative.

The third error is your check for positive.  You should be comparing `list[i]` to see if it is negative, not `n`:

```
if (n>=0)
```

should be

```
if (list[i] >= 0)
```

So the fix for your code would seem to be this:

```
void pullpositivenumbers(ofstream& out, int n, int list[], int positive[])
{
  int i;
  int j = 0;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  if ( list[i] >= 0)
  {
     positive[j] = list[i];
     ++j;
  }
}
```

Now, having said all of this, your entire logic can be replaced by a few algorithm function calls, and no loops need to be introduced, either for getting the negatives or positive values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    // your test values
    int values[] = {51, 144, 5, 16, 8, 0, -2, 14, 6, -4, 173, 263, 11, 9345, -135, 777};

    // partition negatives to left, positives to right of partition
    auto it = std::stable_partition(begin(values), end(values), [] (int i) { return i < 0;});

    // copy positives to vector
    std::vector<int> positives;
    copy_if(it, end(values), back_inserter(positives), [] (int i) { return i > 0;});

    // sum negatives
    // number of negatives is known, by getting the distance
    // between the start of the array and where partition point is
    size_t numNegatives = std::distance(begin(values), it);

    // get the sum of those negative numbers
    int sum = accumulate(begin(values), it, 0);

    // get the average
    double avg = 0;
    if ( numNegatives > 0 )
       avg = static_cast<double>(sum) / numNegatives;

    // output results
    cout << "Here are the negatives:\n";
    copy(begin(values), it, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << "\nSum: " << sum << "\n";
    cout << "Avg: " << avg << "\n\n";

    // Output the positive numbers
    cout << "Here are the positive:\n";
    copy(positives.begin(), positives.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
}
```

Note the usage of `std::stable_partition` to change the order so that negatives and positives are arranged in such a way that the negatives fall to the left, positives fall to the right of the partition point (`it`).

Also, the usage of `std::accumulate` to add up the negatives is done with the code above.  Copying to output also uses `std::copy` to stream the output to `cout`.

So as you can see, no hand-written loops whatsoever to process the data.  Instead the code is more declarative (partition, accumulate, copy, copy_if).

Also, I used `std::vector` to store the positives.  This will make sure that we are not limited to 50 input items when storing positives, plus it is easier to erase any 0's that may be in the vector.  If you still wanted to stick with the (unsafe) `positive` array, then this line:

```
    // copy positives to vector
    std::vector<int> positives;
    copy(it, end(values), back_inserter(positives));
```

would be replaced with this:

```
    // copy positives to vector
    int positives[50];
    //...
    // get number of positives
    size_t numItems = std::distance(it, end(values));

    // copy this number of items or 50 items, whichever is smaller, to the positives array
    copy(it, it + std::min(50, numItems), positives));
```

Note how we throttle the number of items to a max of 50 items.

[See Live Example](http://ideone.com/muDvaa)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program written based on what I think you are trying to achieve. I have included a utility class with a handful of useful functions. It has error handling capabilities. In my larger projects I have actual classes that will log to both the console and or text file, handle exceptions, to manage file handles to read and write to specific types such as a basic text file, texture (image) file, or custom data structure file types. I did not include these for it would make this small simple program for a basic task to large to present taking away from the implementation and algorithm that is needed. I stripped down my reusable library and only included what I thought was needed and maybe a few other useful helpful functions. This code is clean of bugs and works quite well for many common tasks.

**stdafx.h**

```
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_H

//#define VC_EXTRALEAN

//#include <Windows.h>
//#include <process.h>

//#include <memory>
//#include <numeric>

#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
//#include <regex> - included in <queue> and <array> - needed for std::transform
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

enum ReturnCode {
    RETURN_OK = 0,
    RETURN_ERROR = 1,
}; // ReturnCode

#endif // STDAFX_H
```

I commented out common basic useful includes that were not needed in this situation, and removed all other includes that are completely irrelevant such as DirectX, OpenGL, OpenAL, OggVorbis, GLM includes etc.

**stdafx.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

**Utility.h**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

class Utility {
public:

    static void pressAnyKeyToQuit();

    static std::string  toUpper( const std::string& str );
    static std::string  toLower( const std::string& str );
    static std::string  trim( const std::string& str, const std::string elementsToTrim = " \t\n\r" );
    static std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty = true ); 

    static unsigned     convertToUnsigned( const std::string& str );
    static int          convertToInt( const std::string& str );
    static float        convertToFloat( const std::string& str );    

private:
    Utility(); // Private - Not A Class Object
    Utility( const Utility& c ); // Not Implemented
    Utility& operator=( const Utility& c ); // Not Implemented

    template<typename T>
    static bool stringToValue( const std::string& str, T* pValue, unsigned uNumValues );

    template<typename T>
    static T getValue( const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder );

}; // Utility

#include "Utility.inl"

#endif // UTILITY_H
```

**Utility.inl**

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// stringToValue()
template<typename T>
static bool Utility::stringToValue(const std::string& str, T* pValue, unsigned uNumValues) {
    int numCommas = std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ',');
    if (numCommas != uNumValues - 1) {
        return false;
    }

    std::size_t remainder;
    pValue[0] = getValue<T>(str, remainder);

    if (uNumValues == 1) {
        if (str.size() != remainder) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::size_t offset = remainder;
        if (str.at(offset) != ',') {
            return false;
        }

        unsigned uLastIdx = uNumValues - 1;
        for (unsigned u = 1; u < uNumValues; ++u) {
            pValue[u] = getValue<T>(str.substr(++offset), remainder);
            offset += remainder;
            if ((u < uLastIdx && str.at(offset) != ',') ||
                (u == uLastIdx && offset != str.size()))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
} // stringToValue
```

**Utility.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utility.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// pressAnyKeyToQuit()
void Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit() {
    std::cout << "Press any key to quit" << std::endl;
    _getch();
} // pressAnyKeyToQuit

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// toUpper()
std::string Utility::toUpper(const std::string& str) {
    std::string result = str;
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::toupper);
return result;
} // toUpper


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// toLower()
std::string Utility::toLower(const std::string& str) {
    std::string result = str;
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::tolower);
    return result;
} // toLower

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// trim()
// Removes Elements To Trim From Left And Right Side Of The str
std::string Utility::trim(const std::string& str, const std::string elementsToTrim) {
    std::basic_string<char>::size_type firstIndex = str.find_first_not_of(elementsToTrim);
    if (firstIndex == std::string::npos) {
        return std::string(); // Nothing Left
    }

    std::basic_string<char>::size_type lastIndex = str.find_last_not_of(elementsToTrim);
    return str.substr(firstIndex, lastIndex - firstIndex + 1);
} // trim

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getValue()
template<>
float Utility::getValue(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder) {
    return std::stof(str, &remainder);
} // getValue <float>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getValue()
template<>
int Utility::getValue(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder) {
    return std::stoi(str, &remainder);
} // getValue <int>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getValue()
template<>
unsigned Utility::getValue(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder) {
    return std::stoul(str, &remainder);
} // getValue <unsigned>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// convertToUnsigned()
unsigned Utility::convertToUnsigned(const std::string& str) {
    unsigned u = 0;
    if (!stringToValue(str, &u, 1)) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to unsigned";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return u;
} // convertToUnsigned

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// convertToInt()
int Utility::convertToInt(const std::string& str) {
    int i = 0;
    if (!stringToValue(str, &i, 1)) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to int";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return i;
} // convertToInt

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// convertToFloat()
float Utility::convertToFloat(const std::string& str) {
    float f = 0;
    if (!stringToValue(str, &f, 1)) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to float";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return f;
} // convertToFloat

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// splitString()
std::vector<std::string> Utility::splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty ) {
    std::vector<std::string> vResult;
    if ( strDelimiter.empty() ) {
        vResult.push_back( strStringToSplit );
        return vResult;
    }

    std::string::const_iterator itSubStrStart = strStringToSplit.begin(), itSubStrEnd;
    while ( true ) {
        itSubStrEnd = search( itSubStrStart, strStringToSplit.end(), strDelimiter.begin(), strDelimiter.end() );
        std::string strTemp( itSubStrStart, itSubStrEnd );
        if ( keepEmpty || !strTemp.empty() ) {
            vResult.push_back( strTemp );
        }

        if ( itSubStrEnd == strStringToSplit.end() ) {
            break;
        }

        itSubStrStart = itSubStrEnd + strDelimiter.size();
    }

    return vResult;

} // splitString
```

I have removed quite of few functions from my Utility class. For example I have other convert functions that will convert a string into a GLM::Vec2, Vec3, Vec4 object for ints, floats and doubles, convert to different custom enumerations etc. And other functions for testing different things. Instead of having a bunch of common useful functions that just float around that deal with basic repetitive tasks most of them working with simple strings, conversions, testing common conditions, etc., I like to have them in a class where the class acts as a container with all of these functions being declared as static. If you notice the constructor is private and the class has no member variables only methods. You can not create a Utility Object. It works similar to a namespace where all you need to use is the scope resolution operator to access the utility functions.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utility.h"

void parseLine( std::string& strLine, std::vector<int>& vPositiveInts, std::vector<int>& vNegativeInts ) {
    if ( strLine.size() == 0 ) {
       // Skip Blank Line
        return;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> vElements = Utility::splitString( strLine, " " );

    int value = 0;
    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < vElements.size(); u++ ) {
        value = Utility::convertToInt( vElements.at( u ) );

        if ( value > 0 ) {
            vPositiveInts.push_back( value );
        } else if ( value < 0 ) {
            vNegativeInts.push_back( value );
        } else {
            // value = 0? Not Sure What User Wants To Do With 0
            continue;
        }
    }

} // parseLine

int main() {

    try {
        std::string strFilename;

        std::cout << "Enter the filename to read in data." << std::endl;    
        std::getline( std::cin, strFilename );

        std::fstream in;
        in.open( strFilename.c_str(), std::ios_base::in );
        if ( !in.is_open() ) {
            std::ostringstream strStream;
            strStream << "Error reading in file " << strFilename << std::endl;
            throw strStream.str();
        }

        if ( in.eof() ) {
            std::ostringstream strStream;
            strStream << "No Data in " << strFilename << std::endl;
            throw strStream.str();
        }
        std::string strLine;
        std::getline( in, strLine );

        std::vector<int> vPositiveInts;
        std::vector<int> vNegativeInts;

        parseLine( strLine, vPositiveInts, vNegativeInts );


        std::cout << "\nPositive Integers" << std::endl;
        for ( unsigned u = 0; u < vPositiveInts.size(); u++ ) {
            std::cout << vPositiveInts.at( u ) << " ";
        }       
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "\nNegative Integers" << std::endl;
        for ( unsigned u = 0; u < vNegativeInts.size(); u++ ) {
            std::cout << vNegativeInts.at( u ) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

        // User Can Use Similar Methods To Write Data To Their Corresponding Files
        // And Perform The Appropriate Calculations On This Data Using The Vectors Above

    } catch ( std::string& str ) {
        std::cout << "Exception Thrown: " << str << std::endl;
        Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit();
        return RETURN_ERROR;
    } catch ( ... ) {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " Caught Unknown Exception" << std::endl;
        Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit();
        return RETURN_ERROR;
    }

    Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit();
    return RETURN_OK;
} // main
```

This works based on data in the text file being on single line separated by a space. This can be modified slightly if there are multiple lines in the file, or if the delimiter is something else such as a comma or semi colon. I did not write the code to write these values to a file nor write any code to do any calculations on the above data as I will leave that for you to accomplish. I did however print them to the console. I just simply showed you how to easily separate the integers into two groups positive and negatives. Also as a note, any 0s that are found in the string from the file are discarded and are not take into account for. There is another else statement that just continues when a 0 is accounted for. You could add these into the positive case by changing the comparison in the first if statement, but since 0 is not positive nor negative I did not include it in either. You could have another `vector<int>` to store all 0s just to keep track of them if you want.

**integers.txt**

```
51 144 5 16 8 0 -2 14 6 -4 173 263 11 9345 -135 777
```

**Program Output**

> ```
> Enter the filename to read in data.
> integers.txt
>
> Positive Integers
> 51 144 5 16 8 14 6 173 263 11 9345 777
>
> Negative Integers
> -2 -4 -135
>
> Press any key to quit
> ```

Comment: @Anon If you have any problems with writing these to a file just leave a comment below and I may post a second answer to help you with that or give you suggestions on how to achieve it.